# process.StandardError don't redirect output wheres process.StandardOutput does

Tags: c#, process, output

Hey guys i have actually two problems. When i use process.StandardError i get the same result as when i use process.StandardOutput. Why is that?

Additional, when i use process.StandardError it is written to the console window whereas it is written to my buglist.txt when i use process.StandardOutput. Any suggestions?

```
//Make Screenshot of Client Setup 
OutputHandler.ColorCMDOutput("           + Make a Screenshot", 
ConsoleColor.Gray);
Process makeScreenshot = new Process();
makeScreenshot.StartInfo.FileName = screenShotTool;
makeScreenshot.StartInfo.Arguments = "/f \"" + testResult + "\\Screenshots\\" + screenShotName + ".png\"";
makeScreenshot.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
makeScreenshot.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
makeScreenshot.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
makeScreenshot.Start();

//Start StreamReader
StreamReader myStreamReader = makeScreenshot.StandardError;
string error = makeScreenshot.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

//Read the standard error
OutputHandler.AppendDataToFile(buglist, error);

makeScreenshot.WaitForExit();
makeScreenshot.Dispose();
```

Comment: Hey John, i don't use these two properties together. I first tested with StandardOutput and afterwards with StandardError. Whereas StandardError is the information i want to have.

Comment: Yes. The StandardError delivers the same information as the StandardOutput does.